# SQL server 複数バージョンインストールして共存できますか？

Tags: sql-server

SQL server 2008 R2 がインストールされているWindows server 2012上にSQL server 2016をインストールして別名のインスタンスを作成すれば共存可能でしょうか？エディションはstandardです。

ポート番号は変更が必要な認識です。

SQL Management Studioも新旧バージョンで共存可能かも分かりましたらご教示頂けると助かります。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Server の複数のバージョンおよびインスタンスの使用](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/sql-server/install/work-with-multiple-versions-and-instances-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016)で説明されていますが、アップグレードだけでなく、サイドバイサイドインストールもサポートしているため、共存可能です。
SQL Server Management Studioについても、メジャーバージョンが同じ場合に共有されてしまいますが、2008 R2と2016のように異なるバージョンであれば共存可能です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。使用するポート番号は、インスタンス名が異なれば両方のバージョンで同じポート番号を使用することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: @mame ポートの共存は無理です。そもそもどちらに接続されるか制御できませんし。